# What is the difference between android:layout_alignRight="ID" and android:layout_toRightOf="ID"?

Tags: android, layout, alignment

What is the difference between `android:layout_alignRight="@id/someId"` and `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/someId"`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This picture will explain the difference :

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`layout_alignRight` aligns the right edges of the two views.

`layout_toRightOf` aligns the left edge of this view with the right edge of the other `someId` view.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Thanks you great explanation